# Marshal C# Method to Unity3D with C++

Tags: c#, c++, linux, unity-game-engine, marshalling

I would like to call a specific method in my Unity3D project within an external plugin. Here is my C++ code:

```
static void UNITY_INTERFACE_API OnRenderEventThreadSafe(int eventID)
{
    [...] Some C++ code
    //Call C# Method here
}
```

My C++ code does already work on its own but now I want to call a specific C# method. How can I manage to do this? I tried creating delegates like this

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
[DllImport("lib")]
#else
[DllImport ("lib")]
#endif
private static extern void Method(Delegate callback);

private delegate void Delegate(int number);

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Delegate))]
private static void DelegateMessageReceived(int number)
{
    Debug.Log("MessageReceived " + number);
}

public static void Method2()
{
    Method(DelegateMessageReceived);
}
```

But I don't think this is the right way...
Should have mentioned it earlier, but I'm coding on Linux-Fedora25

Comment: Have a look at C++/CLI

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the-same issue in the past when making rendering plugin but the solution is not really hard.

You need to create a global `static`  **function pointer** to hold the *C#* function you want to call from C++. The C++ function pointer must be `static`. Initialize this variable from the `Start` or `Awake` function in C#. After this, you can freely call that function anytime from C++.

**C++** (`YourCppPlugin.h`)

```
#define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"
{
    //Create a function pointer and give it a callback alias to shorten it
    typedef void(*FuncCallBack)(int eventID);

    //Create a callback delegate from the alias to hold the function from C#
    static FuncCallBack callbackInstance = nullptr;

    //Create the function that will be called from C# to store the function
    DLLExport void RegisterRenderCallback(FuncCallBack cb);
}
```

**C++** (`YourCppPlugin.cpp`):

```
#include "YourCPP.h"

//Save the function we received from C# to the global variable for future use:

void RegisterRenderCallback(FuncCallBack cb) {
    callbackInstance = cb;
}
```

Done. You can now use the `callbackInstance` variable to call the C# function anytime from the Unity's `UNITY_INTERFACE_API OnRenderEventThreadSafe` C++ API function. Just make sure it's not `null` before calling it like below:

```
static void UNITY_INTERFACE_API OnRenderEventThreadSafe(int eventID)
{
    [...] Some C++ code

    //Call C# Method here
     if (callbackInstance != nullptr)
        callbackInstance(eventID);
}
```

Register a function to it first from C# with the `RegisterRenderCallback` function first before using the `callbackInstance` variable. See example in the `Start` function  below.

---

**C#** side of the code:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    //Register the OnRenderCallback function to our C++ plugin for a callback
    RegisterRenderCallback(OnRenderCallback);
}

//Function that registers a local C# function to a delegate in C# for later use
[DllImport("YourCppPlugin", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void RegisterRenderCallback(renderCallback cb);

//int param callback delegate that links to the C# function we want to call from C++
delegate void renderCallback(int eventID);

//Function we want to call from C#. Registered in the Start function
[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(renderCallback))]
static void OnRenderCallback(int eventID)
{
    Debug.Log("Called from C# with ID: " + eventID);
}
```

---

Finally, if you have more than one function to register, you have to use List, array or dictionary to hold them on both C# and C++ side then iterate and call each one when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I have some issues with this, my bad that I didn't think about saying it in my question.
I am working on Fedora, so I don't think I can use DLLExport

Comment: Did you actually try to compile this before making that comment?
 `DLLExport ` is a variable defined by me that references `__declspec` which is used to export the functions. Maybe you wanted to say that `__declspec`  is not supported? I don't know your compiler but GNU should work fine with that. Anyways, use `extern "C"` when on Linux. I am already using that in my answer so just remove all references to  `DLLExport`  if having problems compiling it. Remove `#define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)` and then `DLLExport` that is put before the `RegisterRenderCallback` function in the C++ side

Comment: I actually tried compiling but I have this issue:
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 #define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport);
                             ^
../../source/CallbackManager.h:11:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DLLExport’
     DLLExport void RegisterRenderCallback(FuncCallBack cb);

Comment: If I remove DLLExport I can compile but when I start Unity I get the EntryPointNotFoundException for RegisterRenderCallback

Comment: Few comments in case other people are struggling with the same: DLLExport is only needed on Windows; if you get EntryPointNotFoundException this may mean that you need to use IL2CPP to compile and need to run this on an actual device.